# adding large rules on infopath error submitting to sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-online, infopath, calculated-column-formula

I am trying to create a white `list`, so that when a user enters an IP address that's in this list, the field turns red.
I created a rule like `if contains "10.0.0.0" turn red` etc. 
Problem is my white list is about 1300 strong. I've tried adding the formula in expressions like

> dfs:dataFields/my:SharePointListItem_RW/my:Title = "10.10.10.10" or 
>   dfs:dataFields/my:SharePointListItem_RW/my:Title = "10.10.10.11" or

**(please note using 10 address for privacy reasons).**
If I put over 50 of them, I get syntax/parsing error when trying to publish.
I also have no access to the server or admin

Answer (score 0):

Check these links out -
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/30c94d85-631f-427d-8ab9-48956cf96717/check-if-an-item-by-same-title-exists-in-sharepoint-list?forum=sharepointgeneralprevious

http://sharepointbloggin.com/2010/02/10/walkthrough-4-accessing-list-data-using-the-javascript-client-om/

This might give you some understanding about this.
However, this is not achieved through Infopath.

Comment: Stop giving link-only answers. Add relevant parts from the link to your post to make it helpful even if the link breaks